# ¿Cómo poner todos los botones en línea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Con una muestra de código estoy creando botones de compartir. Es un primer botón del que al pasar el ratón aparecen los dichos botones.

En principio eran 4 botones y yo añadí otro más.

El problema es que este aparece por abajo en vez de hacerlo, en línea como los otros.

Otro problema, que verán en el ejemplo, es que al cargar la página los botones aparecen abiertos, lo cual no debería de pasar hasta que no pasáramos el ratón, y todo es a raíz de haber añadido el quinto.

¿Qué debo modificar para que aparezcan los cinco (o los que fueran necesarios) en línea y que no aparezcan expandidos antes de pasar el ratón?

Dejo la muestra:

```js
// Force a hover to see the effect
var share = document.querySelector('.share');

setTimeout(function () {
  share.classList.add("hover");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
  share.classList.remove("hover");
}, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: #e5eef3;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f1ce64;
  font-size: 28px;
}

a {
  color: #f1ce64;
}

.share {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
.share span {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.share nav {
  font-size: 0;
}
.share a {
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 3px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.share a:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.share a:nth-child(1):hover {
  background-color: #61c5ec;
}
.share a:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}
.share a:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: #ea4335;
}
.share a:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: #D40AC0;
}
.share a:nth-child(5) {
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.share a:nth-child(5):hover {
  background-color: #064D96;
}
.share:hover span, .share.hover span {
  opacity: 0;
}
.share:hover a, .share.hover a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #f1ce64;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.share:hover a:hover, .share.hover a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Social share button</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="share">
    <span>Share</span>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cambia el width de 400 a 500 para el elemento .share, pues al añadir uno más no caben.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas es darle más espacio al contenido (500px de ancho, por ejemplo) cambiando:

```
.share {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px; /* Nuevo ancho */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px; /* Nuevo ajuste de centrado */
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
```

Para que quede correctamente centrado hay que cambiar el desplazamiento a la mitad de los 500px (250px).

Aquí tienes el ejemplo funcionando en una única línea:

```js
// Force a hover to see the effect
/*var share = document.querySelector('.share');

setTimeout(function () {
  share.classList.add("hover");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
  share.classList.remove("hover");
}, 3000);*/
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: #e5eef3;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f1ce64;
  font-size: 28px;
}

a {
  color: #f1ce64;
}

.share {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
.share span {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.share nav {
  font-size: 0;
}
.share a {
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 3px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.share a:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.share a:nth-child(1):hover {
  background-color: #61c5ec;
}
.share a:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}
.share a:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: #ea4335;
}
.share a:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: #D40AC0;
}
.share a:nth-child(5) {
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.share a:nth-child(5):hover {
  background-color: #064D96;
}
.share:hover span, .share.hover span {
  opacity: 0;
}
.share:hover a, .share.hover a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #f1ce64;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.share:hover a:hover, .share.hover a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Social share button</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="share">
    <span>Share</span>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Si quieres que no se muestren abiertos al inicio únicamente debes comentar el código que usas para forzar las animaciones.

Comment: ¿ Debo comentar todo el código javascript, o solo parte de él? Gracias por la ayuda @Oscar Garcia.

Comment: Si quieres que no se abra y cierre en la carga debes quitar todo el código que he comentado. Es el culpable de que tras un segundo se abra y tras otros dos más se cierre y como puedes ver no es necesario para el funcionamiento normal del efecto.

Comment: Garcia. Ya he comentado como has sugerido, gracias

Comment: De nada, un placer :)

Answer (score 4):

El elemento tiene un tamaño definido por píxeles, para añadir un nuevo sub-elemento y que no haga el salto de línea simplemente bastaría con aumentar el ancho del elemento:

```
.share {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px; /* <-- Cambio en el ancho*/
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
```

Cambios en tu ejemplo:

```js
// Force a hover to see the effect
var share = document.querySelector('.share');

setTimeout(function () {
  share.classList.add("hover");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
  share.classList.remove("hover");
}, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: #e5eef3;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f1ce64;
  font-size: 28px;
}

a {
  color: #f1ce64;
}

.share {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
.share span {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.share nav {
  font-size: 0;
}
.share a {
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 3px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.share a:nth-child(1) {
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.share a:nth-child(1):hover {
  background-color: #61c5ec;
}
.share a:nth-child(2):hover {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}
.share a:nth-child(3):hover {
  background-color: #ea4335;
}
.share a:nth-child(4):hover {
  background-color: #D40AC0;
}
.share a:nth-child(5) {
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.share a:nth-child(5):hover {
  background-color: #064D96;
}
.share:hover span, .share.hover span {
  opacity: 0;
}
.share:hover a, .share.hover a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #f1ce64;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.share:hover a:hover, .share.hover a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Social share button</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="share">
    <span>Share</span>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @Hechi por la ayuda, solo puedo aceptar una respuesta y la primera que vi fue la del compañero. Gracias.